# Facebook sdk 3.5 crashes on ios 4.3+

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

We have an app which is live in the app store with facebook sdk 3.5
We get crashes from people using ios 4.3
Facebook has written in it's website that the sdk doesn't work on ios lower than ios5
(it was not written in the upgrades guides so we missed it)

Is there a way in the code that we can disable the facebook functionality just on 4.3 devices so facebook won't crash on them?